# Rails 4 + Single Table Inheritance: Implementing 3 types of coupons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a store and am looking for advice on how to architect the coupons part of the site. I have 3 types of coupons:

1. Free shipping
2. Percentage amount
3. Flat amount

The thing is, the way the discounts are applied are all pretty different, so I'm wondering if I should make 3 different tables/models or use single table inheritance and use the template pattern and override a `apply_discount` instance method that is defined in the parent class.

Here's what I'm thinking, although it doesn't seem too clean since some columns are specific to a model:

I will make a `Coupon` model and `coupons`table with it, that will be the parent class. It'll have `type` for references to subclasses `FreeShippingCoupon`, `PercentageCoupon`, and `FlatCoupon`. The columns will be:

1. start_date
2. end_date
3. minimum_purchase_amount
4. percentage (this will only be used/set in the `PercentageCoupon` subclass)
5. flat_amount (this will only be used/set in the `FlatCoupon` subclass)

And in my models I'll have these methods:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

  def apply_coupon(order)
    raise 'Not Implemented'
  end

end

class FlatCoupon < Coupon

  def apply_coupon(order)
    order.total = order.total - self.flat_amount
  end

end

class PercentageCoupon < Coupon

  def apply_coupon(order)
    order.total = order.total * (1 - self.percentage)
  end

end

class FreeShippingCoupon < Coupon

  def apply_coupon(order)
    order.shipping = 0
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a cleaner solution than this. It's not perfect since the columns are not really being shared, but I think it's good this way in comparison to having 3 different tables so I create them with a single `form_for` without getting too messy and also for validations. I don't expect the table(s) to have any additional columns, since coupons are pretty generic and don't change. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single column for the amount that the coupon is worth, and interpret it differently per subclass. It'd replace the `percentage` and `flat_amount` columns with a single `value` column and use in both classes.

e.g.

```
class FlatCoupon < Coupon

  def apply_coupon(order)
    order.total = order.total - self.value
  end

end

class PercentageCoupon < Coupon

  def apply_coupon(order)
    order.total = order.total * (1 - self.value)
  end

end
```

```

Comment: Yeh I was thinking that too. Perhaps I can just use the same data structure (decimal probably) and just handle them differently. Thanks